# Loop in a dataset simulation

Tags: r, simulation, exponential, exponential-distribution

I hope to get help on the following problem in R.

I have the folowing code to generate 30 column dataset based on an exponential distribuition:

```
x0=0
xmax=8000
xout=3000
lambda=0.0002
n=1

  x1=x0+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x2=x1+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x3=x2+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x4=x3+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x5=x4+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x6=x5+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x7=x6+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x8=x7+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x9=x8+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x10=x9+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x11=x10+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x12=x11+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x13=x12+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x14=x13+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x15=x14+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x16=x15+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x17=x16+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x18=x17+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x19=x18+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x20=x19+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x21=x20+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x22=x21+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x23=x22+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x24=x23+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x25=x24+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x26=x25+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x27=x26+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x28=x27+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x29=x28+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  x30=x29+rexp(n,lambda)-xout
```

I have three doubts:

1 - Is there any way to write this function in a reduced form?

2 - This row (30 columns) needs to be simulated 10,000 times. How to do this in a loop?

3 - The values ​​of each cell (x1, x2, x3 ...) must be limited to the interval x0 and xmax (0-8000). How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm fairly new to R myself, I thought it would be good practice to try to write this out. Perhaps not the most efficient code, but it works:

```
xmax <- 8000
xout <- 3000
lambda <- 0.0002
n <- 1
iterations <- 30

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 31, nrow = iterations))
names(df) <- c(paste("x", 0:30, sep=""))

for (j in 1:iterations) {
  df$x0[j] <- 0
  df$x1[j] <- df$x0[j] + rexp(n,lambda)-xout
  if (df$x1[j] < 0) {
    df$x1[j] <- 0
  }
  if (df$x1[j] > 8000) {
    df$x1[j] <- 8000
  }
  for (i in 3:31) {
    df[j,i] <- df[j, i-1] + rexp(n,lambda)-xout
    if (df[j,i] < 0) {
      df[j,i] <- 0
    }
    if (df[j,i] > 8000) {
      df[j,i] <- 8000
    }
  }
}
```

You can change `iterations` to `30000`, for testing purposes I've used `30`. Also I didn't know if you wanted to limit to `0` and `8000` before or after the next iterations, I've done it before.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you want to do with values over 8000. Here's a solution that just takes those values and wraps them around with a modulo operator.

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- data.frame(x0 = rep(0, n))
for (i in 1:30) {
  new_col <- sym(paste0("x", i))
  old_col <- sym(paste0("x", i - 1))
  test <- test %>% 
    mutate(!!new_col := (!!old_col + rexp(n, lambda) - xout) %% xmax)
}
```

I don't know how familiar you may or may not be with the tidyverse and tidy evaluation, which I've used here liberally. The `!!` operator, combined with `sym()`, turns the variable names into actual variables. The `%>%` operator "pipes" data from one function to the next. The `:=` operator is needed only if you want to make assignments with a `!!` on the lefthand side.

I think this is my first time actually trying to post an answer on StackOverflow, so be easy on me! :)

Comment: Happy first answer!

Comment: Thank you @Gregor! I see you're well-past the first-answer mark. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is there any way to write this function in a reduced form?

I would do it like this. Pretty sure this is equivalent.

```
ncol = 30

row = rexp(ncol, lambda)
row = cumsum(row) - xout * (1:ncol)
```

> 2. This row (30 columns) needs to be simulated 10,000 times. How to do this in a loop?

Use `replicate` with the code above:

```
sim_data = t(replicate(10000, {
  row = rexp(ncol, lambda)
  row = cumsum(row) - xout * (1:ncol)
}))
```

`replicate` gives 10000 columns and 30 rows. We use `t()` to transpose it to 10000 rows with 30 columns.

> 3. The values ​​of each cell (x1, x2, x3 ...) must be limited to the interval x0 and xmax (0-8000). How to do this?

Use `pmin()` and `pmax()`. Not sure if you want this done before or after the cumulative summing...

```
sim_data = t(replicate(10000, {
  row = rexp(ncol, lambda)
  row = cumsum(row) - xout * (1:ncol)
  row = pmax(0, row)
  row = pmin(xmax, row)
  row
}))
```